# Remapping Ctrl-P to Ctrl-O for getting the previous command?

Tags: zsh, tmux

I am using zsh with tmux and I like to have Ctrl-P as a shortcut to 'previous pane'. I would however still keep the original 'previous command' functionality of Ctrl-P and map it to Ctrl-O. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to simply bind Ctrl-P to Ctrl-O in tmux. Add this line in .tmux.conf:

bind -n C-o send-keys C-p

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you’re using emacs mode, place this in one of your zsh startup files:

```
bindkey -rM emacs '^P'
bindkey -M emacs '^O' up-line-or-history
```

- The first line removes the binding for `^P` in the `emacs` keymap.
- The second line binds `^O` to `up-line-or-history`, which by default is bound to `^P`.

Note that this will overwrite `^O`’s default binding to `accept-line-and-down-history`.